# How to disable a link button in a Datalist?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
protected void lnk_Add_Click(object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    Label id = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbl_PID");
    Label lbl_P_Name = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbl_PN");
    Image P_Image = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("Img");
    LinkButton lnkbtn = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnk_Add");
    lnkbtn.Enabled = false;

}
```

I am using above method for Disabling a link button after it has been clicked once but the problem I am facing is that when ever I click on other link button(In other Row) the previous link button which was disable gets enable.

What I want is to disable a linkbutton until I don't enable it from any other event or method.

Comment: What does your Page_Load look like? It sounds like you re-bind the list on every postback.

Comment: yes i think that was the only problem, i was binding the data list again on the page load. I just used If(!IsPostBack) property and my code is working fine .Thanks alot @Micheal

Comment: seem problem like bind datalist on every postpack events, restrict it only on if(!Page.IsPostBack) block..

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `ItemDataBound` event of your `Datalist`

```
void Item_Bound(Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{

         if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
             e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
         {

           var lnkbtn = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lnk_Add");
           lnkbtn.Enabled = false;

         }

}
```

Based on this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemdatabound.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just bind your grid in `If(!IsPostBack)` at your `page_load` event